# Audiobook player for Android

Tags: gratis, android, audio, media-player, audiobook

I'm looking for an audiobook player, or an ordinary audio player that has these features:

- Buttons to move 10 seconds forward and backward.
- Saves the current position between restarts.
- It's free.
- Doesn't have suspicious permissions requirements (or at least is certain to not be malicious).

VLC has the first feature, but not the second, and the built-in Walkman app in my phone (Sony Xperia S) has the second, but not the first.

There are several several hits for Audiobook players in the Google store, but all require Full Network Access + ability to read storage, i.e. they could be uploading my data if they wanted to.

Comment: As there is no answer yet, here's at least a starting point to look at: [FolderPlay & AudioBooks](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=85). I don't listen to audio books, so I cannot say which app precisely does what you need. But the most recommended app in this section is MortPlayer (the audio book variant). If you've found your candidate there, feel encouraged to answer your own question here :)

Comment: Yes, strangely enough VLC does not maintain position for audio, but it does for video.

Answer (score 2):

I had forgotten about that question, but I found out that MX Player actually does a good job.

In particular, it has the most important feature - it remembers positions, per each file. Also, it remembers the last file played, per each directory, so it works well enough for audiobooks that are split into multiple files. Again, it's last file played **per-directory**, so it works even with multiple audiobooks split into multiple files, so long as each audiobook is in its own directory.

It doesn't have a +10/-10 seeking buttons, but you can seek with very good accuracy just sliding your finger across the screen.

Also, it can play audio files even while the phone is locked (although this might require tweaking the settings).

Answer (score 0):

I found a better one - Smart Audiobook Player. Even the free version is full-featured and supports everything that I need.