# Android audiobook player (that remembers position)

Tags: android, audio, media-player, mp3, audiobook

I upload MP3-format audiobooks to my Android (4.x) device, and need an audiobook player that remembers that farthest that I've gotten into any given album (though I'd settle for just remembering position in each file).

Additionally, the files within each album tend to be an hour or longer, so being able to do fine seeking within each file would be great but not required.

Comment: Identical question here: [Audiobook player for Android](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2971/185). Though it has no *answer*, please check my recommendation in the comment whether it might fit your needs.

Comment: @Izzy Yes, very similar, but that question requires it to be free (gratis, I'm assuming by the context).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Mortplayer https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.stohelit.audiobookplayer

It remembers the last point played in each file, has exact times stamp searching as well as skip forward/back by set amounts.

I've been using it for a few years on Windows Mobile, Blackberry and now Android and it's the best I've found.