# Music Player for listening to audio books

Tags: windows, media-player

I listen to my audio books, audio lectures a lot.

I need a music player in my PC that

- runs on Windows
- can remember the latest seconds I listened and keep them in
  a specific place to refer them afterwards, in order to continue listening
  from there.

I've looked some music players such as `AIMP3` that could bookmark music, but I want it happen automatically.

Anybody knows any PC music player for this purpose?

Comment: (For Android: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2971/903)

Comment: If the audio's meta data says it is a podcast or audiobook most players I have seen will remember your position automatically.

Answer (score 3):

To remember the last played position in an audio track you can use [VLC player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) with [VLC srpos plugin](http://vlcsrposplugin.sourceforge.net/):

- free and open source
- Windows
- remember the last played position on a per file basis, not just the last played file

[image]

Comment: Does that remember only for the last played file or on a per file basis?

Comment: @NickWilde  per file basis